# Concatenate variables and files when using include in Swig template

Tags: node.js, twig, template-engine, swig-template

How do I **concatenate variables and files** when using `include` in Swig Template Engine?

For eg: `{% include "_partial/{{some var}}.html" %}`

In twig, I can use `{% include '_partials/' ~ some_variable ~ '.html' %}`, but in Swig it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "+" instead of "~"